# Is this gradient design the entire background image or a separate image in CSS?

Tags: css

I'm trying to recreate a website with these type of designs, but I can't figure out if this is a fixed background image and they just positioned the logos inside of it, or is this a separate image that they downloaded and positioned it on the site?

[image]

I tried to inspect it, but it doesn't show up in the html and only the logos inside the gradient image show in the html

Answer (score 1):

Great question! You just need to explore around a bit more using your web inspector :)

**The answer is that it's:**

- an SVG image
- that is set as the background image in a [`:before` pseudoelement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)
- which is absolutely positioned behind those logos

This is a really handy technique for cases where simply setting a `background-image` on the parent element doesn't provide precise-enough positioning control.

[image: screenshot from Chrome]